# is it possible to get attr value from insede a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried this code but it alerts undefined

```
<?php 
    foreach($result1 as $res1)
    {
            $user_id = 5;
?>
        <form name="wish" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
        <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton" data-wid="<?php echo $res1->user_id; ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" value="" onclick="favfunction()"/>
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>


<script>
    function favfunction()
    {
        calBtn = $(this).attr('data-wid');
        calBtn1 = $(this).attr('data-uid');
        alert(calBtn);
        alert(calBtn1);

    }
</script>
```

when I use

```
    calBtn = $('#calButton').attr('data-wid');
    calBtn1 = $('#calButton').attr('data-uid');
```

it alerts same values.

Comment: You're creating duplicate ids by using the SAME id for all the elements inside your form. That's illegal. dom IDs must be unique across the entire document, and your `$(#calButton)` is missing quotes around the selector: `$('#calButton')`

Comment: if you're using the data attribute.. just do `$(Selector).data('wid');` jQuery parses data attributes into the data object...  starting, I think, in version 1.4.2

Comment: @syed.. don't change the scope of your question with edits.. it was `undefined` before because your jQuery selector had a syntax issue; **now**, we don't know what is in `$res1->user_id`.. is it 5 by chance?

Comment: I take that back.. it's `undefined` because `favfunction` is not an instance method. as for the `$('#calButton`)` portion.. `data-wid` must be 5; therefore, `$res1->user_id` was 5.. but then, I don't think this is the question you're meaning to ask..

Comment: $res1->user_id and $user_id are not equal they both has different values

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is that you pass the DOM object itself into your function

```
onclick="favfunction(this);"
```

And then you can do this in your JS

```
<script>
function favfunction(elm)
{
    var calBtn = $(elm).attr('data-wid');
    alert(calBtn);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, the root of your issue is with using the same `id` for your submit buttons.

```
<form name="wish" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach($result1 as $res1)
    {
        $user_id = 5;
?>
    <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_<?php echo $i; ?>" data-wid="<?php echo $res1->user_id; ?>" data-uid="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" value="" onclick="favfunction(this)"/>

<?php
    $i += 1;
    }
?>
</form>
```

---

there should only be 1 `form` tag in an html document.

elements should not have the same ids, so we're appending a number to the id, that correlates to the iteration of the foreach loop.

---

```
<script>
function favfunction(elm)
{
    var wid = $(elm).data('wid'),
        uid = $(elm).data('uid');

    alert('wid: ' + wid + ' - uid: ' + uid);
}
</script>
```

---

### Code Snippet Sample

*with Sample Php output.*

```js
    function favfunction(elm)
    {
        var wid = $(elm).data('wid'),
            uid = $(elm).data('uid');
  
        alert('wid: ' + wid + ' - uid: ' + uid);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<form name="wish" method="post" action="javascript:void(0);">
  <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_1" data-wid="1" data-uid="5" value="Submit" onclick="favfunction(this)" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_2" data-wid="2" data-uid="5" value="Submit" onclick="favfunction(this)" /> 
  <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_3" data-wid="3" data-uid="5" value="Submit" onclick="favfunction(this)" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_4" data-wid="4" data-uid="5" value="Submit" onclick="favfunction(this)" /> 
  <input type="submit" class="submit_wish1" id="calButton_5" data-wid="5" data-uid="5" value="Submit" onclick="favfunction(this)" /> 
</form>
```